# Makefile grep error

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I need to execute this very short script inside a Makefile:

```
$ TEMP=$(grep -v -e '^\#' -e '^\s*$' config.in)
$ CustomExec $TEMP
```

I tried several ways to do that but the makefile always throws an error.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 different things "inside a makefile" might mean.  Please post one of the "several ways" you tried so we have some clue what you want to do, or at least describe it more clearly.

Assuming you mean that you want to run this in a recipe for `sometarget`, you can do it like this:

```
sometarget:
        CustomExec $$(grep -v -e '^\#' -e '^\s*$$' config.in)
```

You have to escape the dollar signs by doubling them, otherwise make expands them as make variables.

You can go back to the traditional backticks in make recipes to reduce the amount of dollar signs you need:

```
sometarget:
        CustomExec `grep -v -e '^\#' -e '^\s*$$' config.in`
```